# MongoDb opening hours Schema and query for open/closed

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose

How could I store opening hours withing, say, a Venue document so that I could query whether the Venue is currently open.

Each Venue document would contain just an opening and a closing time for each day of the week (maybe just the ones its open?).

I need the ability only to set and list the hours (trivial I guess) and to query based on the current time whether it is open or closed.

Maybe something along these lines? But not sure on the Schema to be honest nor how to query it to check if its open.

```
hours: {
    mon: {open: 9:30, close: 18:00 },
    tue: {open: 9:30, close: 17:30 },
    ...
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't your query just check that the current time is `$gte` open and `$lt` close? (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gte/). If you stored the values as an array, you could use the positional operator to pick today `hours.0` might be `Sunday` for example.

Comment: Yeah that is the idea, however I thought that $gt and $lt only worked on a numerical type and I wasn't sure if converting all times, both in the db and from the system time for comparison was the ideal. That said maybe it is. Also like the idea of an array, can easily use getDate or getUTCDate then to index it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using actual hours, rather store your time as `0 - 1440`, each number being an increment of a minute. Then you'll be able to use `$gte` and `$lte`.

So you'd have:

```
hours: {
  mon: {open: 570, close: 1080 },
  tue: {open: 570, close: 1050 },
  ...
}
```

That's the strategy that I'm using in my app. Of course there are slightly more efficient ways, like storing all the hours for the week in a single array, but your approach is still good.

Comment: Any suggestions on a good way to convert this back to military time? such such as 00:00 or 15:30, etc.

Comment: As a string or a timestamp? You would probably convert it to a string first anyway, in JavaScript: `var military_time = Math.floor(time/60) + ':' + time%60` then use a date/time library like `moment.js` to convert it to a time `var mTime = moment(military_time, "hh:m")

Comment: also use `moment.js`, pretty much the same approach, thanks for the response @adamK

Comment: Perfect, thanks you, didn't know you could set moment with a time like that.