# What is the best practice to handle dates with my model?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing an attractions park API with expressjs and mongodb.

I have the Game model which stands for a attraction.

So the attraction has a range of time when it is open, for example from 10:00 to 13:00. But it might also be open from 16:00 to 18:00.

I want to make the range of time to vary with different day of the week.

So i am struggling how to handle time within this model.

Should i pass a array of objects with opening hour and closing hour?

This is my model up to now:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { 
    type: String, 
    required: true 
  },
  employees: [{ 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Employee'
  }],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }

});

const Game = mongoose.model('Game', GameSchema);

module.exports = Game;
```

Should i handle time the following way?

```
schedule: [{
    opening: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    },
    closing: {
      type: Date,
      required: true
    }
  }]
```

Or is it a better way to handle this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314666/how-to-properly-design-working-hour-schema-for-restaurants-on-mongodb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033367/check-if-current-date-between-two-dates-in-french-mongodb-aggregation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460235/mongodb-opening-hours-schema-and-query-for-open-closed